# How to create view which show dynamic data on button click

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-view

I'm new in odoo and stuck at creating a form view which shows dynamic data on button click.

the scenario is,when i click Next (button), data on the view will change (not updated just show another record data) according to the logic behind

for understanding the problem just see the picture.
[Sample View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ie8U.jpg)

Any help will be appreciated and if this can be achieve form any other way that will also work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your problem you created a new model(dynamic model) and you want to display data of another model in that dynamic model form view and after clicking on next, next record of the model will show right?

Comment: No, data is not coming from another model instead it coming from api call. Every time we click on next button, api called and brings data on the view.